# 2 Variable Integrating Factors for Non-exact Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a non-exact equation $(2y)dx+(3x)dy=0$, find an integrating factor of the form $x^my^n$.

To start this problem, multiply both sides of the given non-exact equation by $x^my^n$ to get:

$(x^my^n)(2y)dx+(x^my^n)(3x)dy=0$ 
$(x^m2y^{n+1})dx+(y^n3x^{m+1})dy=0$

Call the function multiplied by $dx$, $P(x,y)$, and the function multiplied by $dy$, $Q(x,y)$.
In order for the equation to be exact, it must satisfy the equality: $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}.$

Found $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=2x^m(n+1)y^n$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=3(m+1)x^my^n$. I set these equal to each other. I simplified as follows:

$2x^m(n+1)y^n-3(m+1)x^my^n=0$ 
$[2(n+1)-3(m+1)]x^my^n=0$

Since the RHS is zero, the coefficients of the LHS must equal zero to satisfy the equation. So $[2(n+1)-3(m+1)]=0$. From here, rearrange to get $n=\frac{3m+1}{2}$. From this point, how to solve for $n$ and $m$? Where else can this relation between $n$ and $m$ be used to solve for their values?

Comment: We don't actually need a single solution for $m$ and $n,$ any one of the family of solutions you've found will do. (fuller answer on the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive single solution for $m$ and $n,$ as you've pointed out the system is underdefined. However, this isn't actually the goal, to have a viable integrating factor we just need to find *a* solution for $m$ and $n,$ not a *unique* solution.

Let's say we arbitrarily let $m = 1,$ for no particular reason other than that it makes the numbers work out well. By your solution for $n$ we should then have $n = \frac{3(1) + 1}{2} = 2.$ If we multiply both sides by $xy^2$ (with the restrictions that $x, y \neq 0$) we will have

$$2xy^3 dx + 3x^2y^2 dy = 0$$

which can be rewritten in the form

$$d(x^2y^3) = 0 \Rightarrow x^2y^3 = C$$

in the typical exact equation manner. The solution we end up with also ends up working for $y = 0,$ because if $y = 0$ in our original equation then either $x = 0,$ breaking our other restriction, or $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ so $y$ is always $0,$ which satisfies our solution. And by the existence and uniqueness theorem, we are guaranteed that this will be the unique solution whenever $x \neq 0.$

---

This same procedure will work for any choice of $m$ and $n$ which satisfies your relationship: in the general case

$$2x^my^{\frac{3m+1}{2} + 1} dx + 3x^{m+1}y^{\frac{3m+1}{2}} dy = 0$$

Supposing $m \neq -1$ we can rewrite this as:

$$d(\frac{2}{m+1}x^{m+1}y^{\frac{3m+3}2}) = 0$$
$$\frac{2}{m+1}x^{m+1}y^{\frac{3m+3}2} = C$$

And because $C$ is arbitrary we can multiply both sides by $\frac{m+1}{2}$ and then take both sides to the $\frac{2}{m+1}$ to get the same solution as before:

$$x^2y^3 = \overline{C}$$

And if we let $m = -1,$ we get

$$\frac{2}{x} dx + \frac{3}{y} dy = 0$$

$$d(2\ln|x| + 3\ln|y|) = 0$$

$$d(\ln|x^2y^3|) = 0$$

$$\ln|x^2y^3| = C$$

and letting $\overline{C} = \pm e^C,$

$$x^2y^3 = \overline{C}$$